# Can I change values in a SQL array in PHP and resort?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SELECT statement that pulls a limited number of items based on the value of one of the fields.  (ie ORDER BY rate LIMIT 15).

However, I need to do some comparisons that and change the value of rate, and subsequently could alter the results that I want.

I could pull everything (without the LIMIT), alter the rate, re-sort, and then just process the number that I need.  However, I don't know if it's possible to alter values in a php result array.  I'm using:

```
$query_raw = "SELECT dl.dragon_list_id, dl.dragon_id, dl.dragon_name, dl.dragon_level, d.type, d.opposite, d.image, dr.dragon_earn_rate
FROM dragon_list dl
LEFT JOIN dragons d ON d.dragon_id = dl.dragon_id
LEFT JOIN dragon_rates dr ON dr.dragon_id = dl.dragon_id
   AND dr.dragon_level = dl.dragon_level
WHERE dl.dragon_id IN (
                       SELECT dragon_id 
                       FROM dragon_elements 
                       WHERE element_id = 3
                       )
   AND dl.dragon_list_id NOT IN (
                                 SELECT dh.dragon_list_id 
                                 FROM dragon_to_habitat dh, dragon_list dl
                                 WHERE dl.user_id = 1
                                 AND dh.dragon_list_id = dl.dragon_list_id
                                 AND dl.is_deleted = 0
                                 )
   AND dl.user_id = " . $userid . "
   AND dl.is_deleted = 0
ORDER BY dr.dragon_earn_rate DESC, dl.dragon_name
LIMIT 15;";

$query = mysqli_query($link, $query_raw);
if (!$query) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($link);
    exit;
}
$d = mysqli_fetch_array($d_query);
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? Do you want to change the values in `$d` and have them updated into the database? If so, you need to have separate SQL statement to update the database. Changes to the result set in PHP do not go back into the database automatically.

Comment: Also, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: I don't want to update the database itself.  The database has the base rates, and I need to calculate new rates based on certain criteria.  So I don't need the new rates in the database, but if I can alter the result array and then resort the array, and reset it so my while loop will start at the beginning, that would work.

Comment: Yes, you can work (change/modify/sort/whatever) on result set `$d`after `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: So if I loop through the results and change $d['earn_rate'] on a dozen of them.  How do I then re-sort the rows in $d and reset it so I can start the loop over again?

Comment: BTW, you *seem* to have more JOINs than strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of research and some trial and error I found my answers....

Yes, I CAN alter the result rows using something like:

```
$result['field'] = $newvalue;
```

I also learned I could reset the pointer by using:

```
mysqli_data_seek($d_query,0);
```

However, when I reset the counter, I lost the changes I made.  So ultimately, I'm still a little stuck, but individually I had the answers.